# Put rectangle color for each item in list view UWP XAML

Tags: c#, listview, colors, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to put for each item different color of the rectangle, but I know how to do this.

**My XAML Code**

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="47"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="32" Height="32" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Foreground="Black" 
                       FontSize="15" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <x:String>White</x:String>
        <x:String>Red</x:String>
        <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
        <x:String>Blue</x:String>
        <x:String>Green</x:String>
        <x:String>Grey</x:String>
        <x:String>Black</x:String>
    </ListView>
```

[This appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIOW3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a DataTemplate that's referencing the colour as always being `Red` - regardless of your bound value, the `Rectangle`'s `Fill` is still `Red` according to your tag.

In order to fix this, you should replace `<Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>` with `<Rectangle Fill="{x:Bind}" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>`.

The new `{x:Bind}` introduces the relevant `<x:String>`s you set below into the `Fill` property of the `Rectangle`, and as a result means you'll see the right colour.